# Sortable | jQuery UI Start at Position 1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

i have this problem already searched for the answer but still no results so i came here for help.

So i started using today this plugin from jquery "Sortable"

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

And its pretty nice but the position from this plugin always start at 0 to ... and i would like to put this 1 to ..., so instead of starting at 0 i would like to start at 1.

Any help will be appreciated,

The code to insert into database:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','valesilveira4850');
mysql_select_db('valesilveira') or die( "Unable to select database");

parse_str($_POST['pages'], $pageOrder);
foreach ($pageOrder['page'] as $key => $value) {
mysql_query("UPDATE dados SET `posicao` = '$key' WHERE `id` = '$value'") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

And the script from sortable:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#menu-pages").sortable({
update: function(event, ui) {
$.post("ajax.php", { type: "orderPages", pages: $('#menu-pages').sortable('serialize') } );
}
});
});
</script>
```

Cumps.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript array has zero based indexing. If you need to show or input indexes, make +/- 1 adjustments.

Comment: Its working pretty well but the position is what i change in database when i move arround the data with sortable the position always change to 0 to the number of items i have in database and i would like just to change the start from 0 to 1